# Android "No Class Deff. Find Error : org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration"

Tags: android

Hi I am running a Google chat application, and following is the code

```
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Roster;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterEntry;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.filter.MessageTypeFilter;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.filter.PacketFilter;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Packet;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.util.StringUtils;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class FacebookChatActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList();
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private EditText mRecipient;
private EditText mSendText;
private ListView mList;
private XMPPConnection mConnection;
private String mHost, mPort, mService, mUsername, mPassword;
private ConnectionConfiguration mConnConfig;
private String TAG;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    initLayout();
     initGtalk();
 //   initFB();
//
    // Create a connection
    createConnection();

    // login
    loginToXMPP();

}

void initLayout() {
    Log.i("XMPPClient", "onCreate called");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_facebook_chat);

    mRecipient = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.recipient);
    Log.i("XMPPClient", "mRecipient = " + mRecipient);
    mSendText = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.sendText);
    Log.i("XMPPClient", "mSendText = " + mSendText);
    mList = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listMessages);
    Log.i("XMPPClient", "mList = " + mList);
    // Set a listener to send a chat text message
    Button send = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.send);
    send.setOnClickListener(this);

    setListAdapter();
}

void initGtalk() {
    mHost = "talk.google.com";
    mPort = "5222";
    mService = "gmail";
    mUsername = "userid@gmail.com";
    mPassword = "password";
    // Set Default recipients for Gtalk
    mRecipient.setText("rameshchoudury1990@gmail.com");
}

void initFB() {
    mHost = "chat.facebook.com";
    mPort = "5222";
    mService = "xmpp";
    mUsername = "userid@chat.facebook.com";
    mPassword = "password";
    // Set Default recipients for FB
    mRecipient.setText("new_userid@chat.facebook.com");
}

void createConnection() {
    mConnConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(mHost,
            Integer.parseInt(mPort), mService);
    mConnConfig.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.required);
    mConnConfig.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
    mConnection = new XMPPConnection(mConnConfig);

    try {
        mConnection.connect();
        Log.i("XMPPClient",
                "[SettingsDialog] Connected to " + mConnection.getHost());
    } catch (XMPPException ex) {
        Log.e("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Failed to connect to "
                + mConnection.getHost());
        Log.e("XMPPClient", ex.toString());
        setConnection(null);
    }
}

void loginToXMPP() {
    try {
        mConnection.login(mUsername, mPassword);
        Log.i("XMPPClient", "Logged in as " + mConnection.getUser());

        // Set the status to available
        Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
        mConnection.sendPacket(presence);
        setConnection(mConnection);
    } catch (XMPPException ex) {
        Log.e("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Failed to log in as "
                + mUsername);
        Log.e("XMPPClient", ex.toString());
        setConnection(null);
    }
}


/* * Called by Settings dialog when a connection is established with the XMPP
 * server
 * 
 * @param connection*/

public void setConnection(XMPPConnection connection) {
    this.mConnection = connection;
    if (connection != null) {
        // Add a packet listener to get messages sent to us
        PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
        connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
            public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                Message message = (Message) packet;
                if (message.getBody() != null) {
                    String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message
                            .getFrom());
                    Log.i("XMPPClient", "Got text [" + message.getBody()
                            + "] from [" + fromName + "]");
                    messages.add(fromName + ":");
                    messages.add(message.getBody());
                    // Add the incoming message to the list view
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            setListAdapter();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }, filter);
    }
}

private void setListAdapter() {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.multi_line_list_item, messages);
    mList.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.send) {
        String to = mRecipient.getText().toString();
        String text = mSendText.getText().toString();

        Log.i("XMPPClient", "Sending text [" + text + "] to [" + to + "]");
        Message msg = new Message(to, Message.Type.chat);
        msg.setBody(text);
        mConnection.sendPacket(msg);
        messages.add(mConnection.getUser() + ":");
        messages.add(text);
        setListAdapter();
    }

}

}
```

When I am running this code I am getting

```
11-26 16:20:15.283: E/dalvikvm(595): Could not find class org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration', referenced from method com.example.sarojfacebookchat.FacebookChatActivity.createConnection
```

Could anyone explain me about this error and if required please suggest me the correct code. 
I have included asmack2010.05.07.jar into my project

Comment: can you see that added jar under project propeties->java build path->libraries tag ?

Comment: also check the user permissions to the jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only three reasons you will ever get this error:

1. The class genuinely doesn't exist. If you are using code from an official example and getting this, make sure you have the latest build of the library
2. You have not added the jar to your build path. To fix this, right click on the jar in Eclipse, and do Build Path ► Add to Build Path.
3. Your jar is not in the `/libs` folder. This happens when you have added the jar to the build path, but newer versions of ADT need it to be in `/libs`. Put it there and re-add it to the build path.

Mostly, such errors occur because newer versions of the ADT require all external jars to be in the `/libs` folder. Your colleague was probably on a different version than you, and hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

Remove all references to the JAR in your project from Java Build Path.-> your code should not build without error anymore

Create a libs folder if not exist at the root of your project Copy the JAR into the libs folder.

If still not running OK. Right click your project > Android Tools > Fix Project Properties

clean your project and run. it will work

Answer (score 0):

try this way...

1. Right click on your project and go to Properties.
2. go to java build path..//which is on the 5th position on left side
3. go to Order and Export tab.
4. check(Tick Mark) on your selected jar file. and click ok.
5. Now, clean your project and Run.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem too,........ 
The solution was to delete  the smack jars from build path and copy and paste the jar files into the libs folder of the project.